# Count number of users per window using PySpark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm using Kafka to stream a JSON file, sending each line as a message. One of the keys is the user's `email`.

Then I use PySpark to count the number of unique users per window, using their email to identify them. The command

```
def print_users_count(count):
    print 'The number of unique users is:', count

print_users_count((lambda message: message['email']).distinct().count())
```

Gives me the error below. How can I fix this?

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-311ba744b41f> in <module>()
      2     print 'The number of unique users is:', count
      3 
----> 4 print_users_count((lambda message: message['email']).distinct().count())

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'distinct'
```

Here is my PySpark code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json

try:
    sc.stop()
except:
    pass  

sc = SparkContext(appName="KafkaStreaming")
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)

# Define the PySpark consumer.
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, bootstrap_servers, 'spark-streaming2', {topicName:1})

# Parse the incoming data as JSON.
parsed = kafkaStream.map(lambda v: json.loads(v[1]))

# Count the number of messages per batch.
parsed.count().map(lambda x:'Messages in this batch: %s' % x).pprint()
```

Comment: Could you please try this : `print_users_count(parsed.map(lambda message: message['email']).distinct().count())`

Comment: Yepp! I got `AttributeError: 'TransformedDStream' object has no attribute 'distinct'`

Answer (score -1):

Your not applying the lambda function to anything. What is `message` referencing? Right not the lambda function is just that, a function. That si why your getting `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'distinct'`. It is not being applied to any data, so it is not returning any data. You need to reference the dataframe which the key `email` is in.

See the pyspark docs for `pyspark.sql.functions.countDistinct(col, *cols)` and `pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct` [pyspark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html). This should be a simpler solution to getting a unique count.